# Concurrent executions of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have to load 3 billion rows from one database into another with some processing. I have a stored procedure which does the processing and loads the data into the target.

To speed up the process I'm using a primary key column value in source table as a parameter to the stored procedure.

When running the stored procedure in diff sessions it's not performing as expected.

Please let me know how to improve the performance with concurrent executions in different sessions.

EX: if I've the ID's from `1 to 300000`, I'm passing `parameters` as `1 to 1000,1000` to `2000,2000 to 3000`..... to the stored procedure.

```
exec sp1 1,1000----session1
exec sp1 1000,2000----session2
exec sp1 2000,3000---session3
......
...
```

If I run just one process it's finishing fast. But if I run multiple processes it's consuming more time.

Comment: Perhaps the target table is locked. Use `sp_WhoIsActive` to see

Comment: No Nick, it's not getting locked. It's just an insert operation.

Comment: Tables are always locked to various levels when you select, insert, or update. When locking impacts performance it becomes a problem.

Comment: Inserts do "lock" that row and not the entire table. Until that insert row is finished nobody can read/update/delete it. Whlie others can insert rows in that table (even from different sessions).

Comment: Insert will lock a table it needs to write to the primary key index which is a clustered index which is the actual table. Did you look at the execution plans?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, it'a couple of advices:

1. You are right using batches to move data from one table to another. Many batches of small transactions are better than huge one
2. Do not do it in parallel. I'm sure, your code blocks source or destination table. And my experience says not to do it in parallel. Write one loop, fetch batches one by one, and move data
3. Test batch sizes. Usually, batch in 1 million of rows is better than 1000 batches in 1000 rows.
4. Yes, it can take a lot of time. Maybe, you need add some code, that allows users to work, while transfering in process. Hide data behind view, for example